# Will I not be allowed to enter Germany without health insurance?

Tags: international-travel, germany, insurance

I have a flight for next month to visit Germany for about a month from the USA. I have the important things, such as a passport, ID, vaccinations, etc. I have been confused about this, so do I **need** international health insurance otherwise Germany won’t let me enter? Or do I not need it?

Comment: What's your citizenship?

Comment: Mostly if you need insurance it is a travel (emergencies) cover, not a normal (full) health insurance. (And you can buy the travel insurance for relatively little money. Even if you do not need it, it is always advised to get it, small investment but saves a lot of problems and money when you do fall ill or have an accident when abroad.)

Answer (score 1):

Having medical insurance that covers your time in Germany is technically mandatory. However if you don't need a visa for Germany (for example because you are a US citizen), you will not be asked to provide proof of health insurance and there are no minimum requirements for coverage. (I've visited on many occasions and never been asked.)

If you need a visa for Germany you must provide proof of health insurance with certain minimal coverage requirements as part of the visa application process.

Having said that it is always a good idea to have travel health insurance.

[Reference](https://www.germany-visa.org/insurances-germany/travel-insurance/).

Comment: It's not clear to me that travel insurance, specifically, is required. My regular US health insurance will cover me abroad (why not? my health insurance company would far rather pay German prices than American ones anyway), though they won't provide the same sorts of repatriation or air ambulance coverages offered by travel insurance policies. If the OP has regular health insurance that covers them in Germany, that may be sufficient, though they'd want to be sure they know exactly what is and isn't covered.

Comment: If your regular insurance covers travel abroad then that counts a having travel health insurance. And as I said, if you don't need a visa then there is no minimum level of coverage required.

Comment: Many US health insurances (such like an HMO) will not cover you abroad. Others (like a PPO) may provide some cover but are also likely charge you substantial out-of-network and/or co-pay fees and any amount covered will likely count against your deductible. Medical-only Travel Insurance on the other hand is surprisingly cheap and simple.